# Catch exception “missing 1 required positional argument” if I don't send two arguments?

Tags: python

Is it possible to catch exception “missing 1 required positional argument” if I don't send two arguments? How to fix it if I can't change assert functions.

```
def sum (n,m):
   return n+m
if __name__ == '__main__':
   assert sum(16,15) == 31, "EXAMPLE"
   assert sum([16,16]) == 32, "result - missing 1 required positional"
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You can catch that with a try-except, just like with any other exception, but it's not the kind of thing you should be catching in most situations. Why do you want to do that? If you're trying to write a function with a flexible signature, you should be looking at optional arguments and `*args`/`**kwargs` catchall arguments.

Comment: "How to fix it if I can't change assert functions" - the way you're using `assert` makes no sense.

Comment: The second argument to `assert` is an assertion failure message, to be used if the first argument is false. It is not used if evaluating the first argument throws an exception, and it is not compared to the exception message in any way. It doesn't make sense to report an assertion failure with message "result - missing 1 required positional" if `sum([16,16]) == 32` is false.

Comment: Ok, thank You. This is example of my exercise. I think that in this exercise is mistake, because i can't edit assert function. I can only modify my def. If i get list and i have to use function with two arguments... it's no sens. Finally, exercise like this is on the very popular page about python. (This code is short version to simply clarify problem)

Comment: It sounds like you're probably supposed to rewrite `sum` to use optional arguments or `*args`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just put second argument optional. In this situation I don't have to modify my main function.

```
def sum (n,m=0):
if m!=0:
    return n + m
elif type(n)==list:
    return n[0]+n[1]

if __name__=='__main__':
    assert sum(16, 15) == 31, "EXAMPLE"
    assert sum([16, 16]) == 32, "result - missing 1 required positional"
```